# why is c:if condition returning result when condition is false?

Tags: jstl

Here is the code:

```
<h3>before showShipping = [${showShipping}]</h3>
<c:if test="${showShipping eq '5'}">
    <h3>after showShipping = [${showShipping}]</h3> 
</c:if>
```

And the output is:

```
before showShipping = [1]
after showShipping = [1]
```

Why am I seeing the after????

Comment: Rightclick page in webbrowser and do *View page source*. Is the `<c:if>` correctly removed or is it still there? Symptoms suggest that it'll be still there and thus wasn't exeucted, which in turn means that JSTL isn't properly installed/configured/declared. If it's correctly removed, then another probable cause is that the `${showShipping}` isn't a string but a number.

Comment: The <c:if> is still in the HTML, so that explains it... now I need to figure out why it is still there, which is a whole other issue!

Comment: Okay. See abovelinked duplicate for the instructions.